# sending username and password through email after user registration in web application

Tags: security, forms, registration

What is your opinion on sending the username and password to their email address when they register on our website..this way if they forget the password in the future, they can look it up in their email...also we wont have to implent the forget/reset password scenario (we are close to release)..

is this approach safe enough?

2. My second question is that basically on our site, the user fills out certain forms and enter some information like their name, address, phone number, income information and such personal information..at the end, when they submit the application, we are thinking of emailing them a summary of all this information like their name, address etc so that they have it for their records..

is this ok..safe enough..what are the concerns

Comment: just a thought probably not worthy of its own answer below... have you considered using OpenID?  It allows you to sidestep a lot of the security concerns involving account registration and passwords, since you never actually touch the user's password and it's not your responsibility to change it if they forget.

Comment: It might not answer the question, but it's certainly worth a mention. If your audience is technically savvy enough to understand OpenID, use it.

Comment: Agreed. I like the OpenID solution.

Answer (score 25):

*Never send a password or other sensitive information in the clear.* That includes e-mail. You should also be storing as little of this as possible in a recoverable format. Unencrypted communication, especially e-mail, is easily tampered with, and you don't want the wrong people getting at passwords.

If possible:

- Store your passwords in a salted hash, so the original text is unrecoverable, and thus unbreakable by anything short of a brute force attack. If the user forgets his/her password, make them reset it and send a temporary password (which they are *required* to change upon login) or a confirmation link (which, again, prompts for a new password) via e-mail.
- Never send anything sensitive via e-mail; if the user needs information, make them go to your site to get it. You are using HTTPS, right?

Comment: You say to never send a password in the clear, but you suggest sending a temporary password via e-mail. e-mail == insecure.

Comment: Hence the requirement to change it upon login. Resetting one's password via e-mail is insecure no matter how you do it (either a temp password or a URL); the hope is that any information transmitted in the process is obsolete by the time an attacker can get to it. The only real alternative is the secret question mechanism, which can be done over a secure protocol but asks questions that most would-be attackers could simply look up, thus rendering it even less secure than e-mail.

Comment: "the hope is that any information transmitted in the process is obsolete" What if the user doesn't check his email for a week? Believe it or not, this happens. An attacker can easily get the temp password.  The ONLY thing in the email to the user should be "your email was reset."

Comment: Keeping the "resetting password" links sent by email "valid" for a *limited period of time* and *invalid after password reset*, should help against the problem of users forgetting to check "forgotten password" emails (and not removing them after use). See this interesting blog post: http://www.plynt.com/blog/2011/09/forgot-pwd/

Comment: Still it doesn't solve the man-in-the-middle problem. The middle-man can grab your one-time password before you and use it to reset **your** password. In fact, the middle-man could be the one requesting for your password reset, not you yourself. This gives him plenty of time to reset your password until you notice anything is amiss.

Answer (score 5):

People often share passwords across sites.  So you should assume the same password works for the customer's online banking, and you should never send it by e-mail or provide a way for (someone pretending to be) the customer to retrieve it.

It's fine to send them a confirmation e-mail with their username - this is useful.

Remember, if you e-mail them their password they're likely to forget about that e-mail, or just delete it.  So you need another password reset mechanism anyway.

The best way to handle the "forgotten password" case is for the user to request you to e-mail the user a link; when they click the link you allow them to type in a new password.

Regarding personal information (address, income etc): *why* would anyone want this mailed to them?  They already know it!  You're just sending private data unencrypted over the internet for no reason.

Answer (score 4):

My rule of thumb would be - if you're OK writing it on a postcard and sending it through the mail, then it's OK for standard Email.  I don't think income information would fall in that category for most people.

As for passwords, if they can't remember them in the first place, they won't be able to find the Email you sent them with the password in it, and it's an admission of storing it in the clear.  I would avoid it and give them the means to reset - they will need that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The concern is definitely in the sending of the email with the password. If it is not properly encrypted, someone could potentially sniff the packets from the email being sent and recover the password. Also, the person could potentially have a hijacked email account. If it's not a big deal if someone steals the password then you may not have to worry, but otherwise I would NOT send any unencrypted passwords via email.

Edit: To address your second question, I wouldn't even email that. I would instead send a link so that they can easily see their profile/information when they log in.

Answer (score 2):

I tell people to think of email like a postcard -- an employee of any company that handles it between the sender and the recipient can read it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are sending any information via email, **it won't be secure**.  There are too many ways someone can get it.  It would be child's play for a skilled hacker looking to steal your information.

**Refrain from sending any personal information** like passwords and income information via email as it can become VERY EMBARRASSING for you and your organization if such information was leaked or stolen.  Think about security seriously.  It just takes that one incident for all the bricks to fall.

As for password retrieval, thoroughly read [Forgot Password Best Practices](http://www.fishnetsecurity.com/Resource_/PageResource/White_Papers/FishNetSecurity_SecureForgotPassword.pdf).

> The bottom line is that an application
>   following best practices should allow
>   a user to reset his own password.
>   Personal security questions should be
>   used. The application should not send
>   email, display passwords, nor set any
>   temporary passwords.

EDIT: Updated Link...

Comment: This is assuming that the site is secured with SSL!

Comment: And that the answers to the questions aren't easily guessed or looked up. My mother's maiden name, for example, is public record.

Comment: It's common sense that having one security question would not suffice, especially something like mother's maiden name. Use multiple non-weak security questions.

Comment: Link points resource "page not found". I think this pdf is removed or moved elsewhere. Use this URL: http://www.fishnetsecurity.com/6labs/resource-library/white-paper/best-practices-secure-forgot-password-feature

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the top answer and have this to add: every time I receive a signup confirmation email that contains my password I delete the email and strongly consider never using that web service again. To me, it indicates a lack of security & privacy consciousness.

Answer (score 1):

Most company simply do not include Username password combination due to the security of the external email client.  Any numbers of users could brute force or guess the password to the email account of another users which would allow the hacker to view the email of your site.  Then the hacker could wreak havoc on your site as well

Answer (score 1):

I'd say providing a forgotten password function will still be vital as not everybody will be guaranteed to keep all there emails (or even be able find them later on)...

Answer (score 0):

I have three rules concerning passwords:

> - Don’t store passwords in plain text in the database
>
>   - Why should people trust you with that kind of information? You may only have good intentions, but big companies have failed before, so you're at risk too.
> - Don’t use password reminders
>
>   - [Password reminders are not worth it](http://arstechnica.com/security/news/2009/05/backup-authentication-info-easy-to-guess-hard-to-remember.ars). They are easy to guess from people in your entourage and you often forget them. There are better ways to reset a password.
> - Always offer to send a new password by email
>
>   - This is the most secure way of retrieving passwords. You should force the user to change the password once logged in with the new password.

Comment: Point 3 is prone to DoS attacks. Always send links that allow you to reset a password, don't reset it right away.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you might want to look at OpenID. The most secure way to manage passwords is to eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

I build an Web Application to send sensitive information by email. It's not UI perfect but it's really secure and working very fine.

There an outlook plugin, API to connect external website and the WebSite.

The concept is the message received in your mailbox are not in clear text. It's an HTML email with a link. You need to click the link to access the content of the email. When it's access one time, the message are destroy.

The message are stock in a crypted database on our side. You can configure a password that are know only by the two part to open the message online, or receive an password (Random 6 number) by SMS.

It's very simple to implement by API.

There is a sample

// https://www.secure-exchanges.com/API.aspx

```
 List<string> files = new List<string>();
  files.Add(originalFilePath);
  string input = $"{body}";
  string inputSubject = $"Your {subject}";
  SendMessageAnswer answer = MessageHelper.EncryptMessage(new EncryptMessageArgs(GlobalSettings.bindingSecure, GlobalSettings.serial, GlobalSettings.ApiUser, GlobalSettings.ApiPassword, input, inputSubject + " - to open", recipient1, "", password, null, SecureExchangesSDK.SecureExchanges.SendMethodEnum.onlyEmail, false, true, true, "fr-CA", 1, 5)
  {
    FilesPath = files
  });
  if (answer == null || answer.Status != 200)
  {
    throw new Exception($"Impossible d'envoyé un message : {methodName}");
  }
```