# Password Reset Backend Functionality

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I'm having a little trouble with how to conceptually handle password resets if a user forgets their password. I have been trying to model my system after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102781/best-way-for-a-forgot-password-implementation) SO answer.

Here is my current setup:

1. The user clicks forgot password link on page
2. The page prompts them to enter their email address
3. The user enters email address and hits "Send me my info"
4. When the user hits "Send my my info" a new entry is created in my password_change_requests table with a random id, a time, and the user's username.
5. I send the user a link that is in the format `http://mysite.net/resetpassword.php?id=xxx&username=yyy`
6. The resetpassword.php file GETs the id and username
7. resetpassword.php checks for a row in password_change_requests that has username and a time that is not yet expired
8. If row is found, then make sure the id from get matches hashed id in that row.
9. If the id is validated then echo html with forms and buttons for entering new password
10. Try to send new password to a different php script that verifies new password and confirm new password match. `verifyNewPassword.php`

My design must be flawed somehow because I can't figure out how to send the user back to resetpassword.php if the passwords don't match in verifyNewPassword.php. I can't just give them a link to click sending them back to resetpassword.php, because that link also needs the id and username from GET. I tried sending that GET data from resetpassword.php to verifyNewPassword.php, but I can't figure it out since the html is inside an echo. Here is a summary of my code:

resetpassword.php:

```
if ($tokenFound) {
    echo "<html>
<body>
<h1>Password Reset</h1>
<form action='verifyNewPassword.php' method='post'>
<input type='password' name='password' placeholder='New Password'><br>
<input type='password' name='confirmpassword' placeholder='Confirm New Password'><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='Reset Password'>
</form>

</body>
</html>";
  }
  else {
    //notify user token is expired or not found. try to reset password again
    echo "not a valid token";
  }
```

verifyNewPassword.php:

```
if ($password != $confirmpassword) {
    print "Passwords don't match. Click <a href=\"resetpassword.php\">here</a> to try again.<br/>";
  }
  else {
    echo "passes match";
  }
```

Comment: You could consider deleting all your code (and headaches) and using this instead: http://www.php-login.net/

Comment: i think your `verifyNewPassword.php` should be inside `if ($tokenFound)` section. because here also you have to verify the token. or anybody can change password of anybody. you should also post `id` and `username` back in hidden fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any way you write this, you *will* need these `xxx` and `yyy` values in verifyNewPassword.php. The best solution would save these in hidden inputs when passed to resetpassword.php, send them along with the POSTed values, and verify them one more time from verifyNewPassword.php.

If you want to avoid the link, you can send a 303 response with the `Location` header set to `http://mysite.net/resetpassword.php?id=xxx&username=yyy`, with another optional flag set if you wanted to display an error message.

Comment: But how do I send along the xxx and yyy values via POST from resetpassword.php? I can't figure out how to do something like <form action='verifyNewPassword.php?id=$id&username=$username' method='post'>.

Comment: Use hidden inputs in the HTML form, and copy the values.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was unaware of the hidden input type of html.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing the id and username values from resetpassword to verify password like so:

```
if ($tokenFound) {
    echo '<html>
<body>
<h1>Password Reset</h1>
<form action="verifyNewPassword.php" method="post">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password"><br>
<input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm New Password"><br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="' . $username . '">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">
<input type="submit" value="Reset Password">
</form>

</body>
</html>';
  }
  else {
    //notify user token is expired or not found. try to reset password again
    echo "not a valid token";
  }
```