# Resetting password, login error after database update

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, passwords

I have built a password reset system in php/silex/twig that gets sends the user a password reset link with a unique token. After the user visits the `confirm-new-password` page the are prompted to enter a new password and confirm that password. I then have a function `confirm_new_password` that checks whether the passwords are the same, if they are update the database of that specific user and then delete the token. This all works fine as I can see in the database that the password changes.

However my problem is that when the user try's to login with their new password I get an error with my flash messages saying that the details are wrong when this is not the case.

As I am using the `password_hash` function I thought that it maybe to do with this however I am hashing the new password before its entered into the database and it is running the check using the `password_verify` function within my `login` function.

Initially I had read [this](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-create-forget-password-form-in-php_381.html) to start of helping build the reset functionality including others to help with generating the random token and one time url with an expiry time.

Afterwards I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691464/password-reset-backend-functionality) which helped me to understand that I need to pass hidden inputs so that the post variables can be updated according which user is resetting their password. But could not seem to get passed the issue of the login after the password is reset.

Here is my function for the confirm-new-password

```
public function confirm_new_password($password1,$password2,$email,$token){

if($password1 === $password2){
        $password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->link,$password1);
        $password1 = password_hash($password1,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $result = mysqli_query($this->link,"update user set password='{$password1}' where email='{$email}' ");
        $result1 = mysqli_query($this->link,"update user set token='' where email = '{$email}' ");
        return true;
}else{
    return false;
}

}
```

and here is the twig template;

```
<form class="form-signin" action="/confirm-new-password" method="post">
<h2 class="form-heading">Confirm New Password</h2>
<label for="inputNewPass1" class="sr-only">New Password</label>
<input type="password" id="inputNewPass1" class="form-control" name="pass1" placeholder="New Password" required>
<label for="inputNewPass2" class="sr-only">Re-Type New Password</label>
<input type="password" id="inputNewPass2" class="form-control" name="pass2" placeholder="Re-type New Password" required>
{% if test is defined %}

    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ test.email }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ test.token }}">
{% endif %}
<div class="spamCheck">
        <label for="inputPostcode" class=sr-only">Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputPostcode" class="form-control" name="postcode" placeholder="Leave this field blank" />
</div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" type="submit">Reset    Password</button>
</form>
```

and here is the post controller code;

```
$app->post('/confirm-new-password', function(Request $request) use($app){
$password1 = $app['request']->get('password1');
$password2 = $app['request']->get('password2');
$email       = $app['request']->get('email');
$token       = $app['request']->get('token');

if($app['auth']->confirm_new_password($password1,$password2,$email,$token)){
    return $app->redirect('/login');
}else{
    return $app->redirect('/');
}

});
```

I should mention that the login is working perfectly fine for other users, it just stops working when the password is reset. Below is the function for the login;

```
    public function login($email, $password) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->link, $email);

    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, "select email, password,type from user where email = '{$email}'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if(password_verify($password,$row['password'])){
            $user = array('email' => $row['email'], 'type' => $row['type']);
            $this->session->set('user', $user);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

  }
```

and here is the post controller method for the login;

```
$app->post('/login', function(Request $request) use($app) {
$email = $app['request']->get('email');
$password = $app['request']->get('password');
$postcode = $app['request']->get('postcode');
$post = array($email,$password,$postcode);
$app['auth']->spamBotCheck($post);
$app['auth']->honeyPotCheck($postcode);

if ($app['auth']->login($email, $password)) {
    $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('success','Success! You are now logged in.');
    return $app->redirect('/');
} else {
    $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('error','Error! There was an error with your login details, please try again');
    return $app->redirect('/login');
}
});
```

I get the flash error, saying there was an error with my login details

Comment: Besides the answer given below; the way I see is that you're using `name="pass1"` and `name="pass2"` yet you're doing `get('password1')` and `get('password2')`. This comment could be a partial answer.

Comment: Wow silly mistake, this solved it.

Comment: Glad to hear it and I've posted it as an additional/complimentary answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment to an additional/complimentary  answer.

Besides the other answer given; the way I see is that you're using `name="pass1"` and `name="pass2"` yet you're doing `get('password1')` and `get('password2')`.

- They need to match.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 1):

```
$password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->link,$password1);  
$password1 = password_hash($password1,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

I would change the order of this rows.
First hash it - than escape it.

Because the way you do it now is, that you escape the password (mypass'w0rd) by adding e.g. some backslashes (mypass\'w0rd) to the original password and after that hash it.

Comment: Duely noted, have changed to this format within my register function as well. However still getting the login error.