# Forgot Password REST resource

Tags: rest, forgot-password

What is the best practice for implementing a REST call for sending out a password.  By this I mean what is best practice for having this as a resource?

/User/ForgotPassword

and then post in the email address for it to be sent to?

To me that seems a little to unRESTful...thoughts.

Kind of a silly questions, but curious what people have to say.

Thanks!

Comment: Offtopic, but please don't send out the actual password and don't store in plain text, reset it and send them that.

Comment: agree on not storing it in plain text, but why not send them their password in the email?

Comment: This covers it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069722/sending-username-and-password-through-email-after-user-registration-in-web-applic/1069799#1069799

Comment: Also read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522967/forgot-password-what-is-the-best-method-of-implementing-a-forgot-password-functi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new resource Email.

Figure this could be used for multiple types of emails that the system will have to send out.

Can also be called on the user resource
/Users/Emails