# Devise Async is not recording the attr_accessor's in Delayed Job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, delayed-job

my app is Rails 3 + Delayed Job (2.1.4) + Devise(2.1.2) + Devise Async (0.3.1).

I'm using this devise setup to have all the devise emails sent async. This works fine for new users but in my invite flow I do the following:

```
added_user = User.new(:email => email, :added_by => current_user, :added_to => @group)
```

The problem here is that added_by and added_to are virtual attributes (attr_accessor). And when Delayed Job Async inserts the jobs in Delayed Job the virtual attributes are not there and errors occur.

Any ideas on how to handle this situation? Is this a Delayed Job issues or Devise Async Issue? I'm not entirely sure where to start and google searches weren't helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you haven't made added_by and added_to accessible via mass-assignment. In later versions of Rails, you can have it raise a `MassAssignmentSecurity` error, but this may not be available or enabled in your case. Try adding the following to your model:

```
attr_accessible :added_by, :added_to
```

Comment: Thanks but they are there. All this works expect for when I use devise-async

Comment: Is the exact object you're instantiating available to the background job?

Comment: no, that's the problem with devise-async, it's just storing the user.id and then fetching the user record in DJ

Comment: Can you pass it any additional options and not put the values directly on the User object? If not, would it be bad to persist the values?

Comment: That's the issue, that's not available with the above.

Answer (score 0):

DelayedJob has significant issues with attribute accessors (so I very much doubt your problem has to do with Devise). Essentially, ActiveRecord::Base's encode_with and init_with methods need to be overridden to include attribute accessors when using DelayedJob -- at least unless you are using custom. I would suggest looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209986/delayed-job-with-custom-attributes) for an idea of how to work around this issue.