# Sending password link to email when user forget password

Tags: php, html, email

I have the problem, how to send a password link to user email when the user clicks the forget password link....

Here is ForgetPasswordViewController.php... i developed this for simply showing a alert...
But when coming to real time.. i don't know how to send the password link.. to user email...

```
    <?php


      header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
      header("Pragma: no-cache");
      header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");
```

//If you are not submitting the form HTML will be directly shown

```
         if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
          {
     ?>
         <html>
         <body>

       <form name='f1' method="POST" action=""  onSubmit="return ValidateEmail();">     
      <div id="fp">
       <span style="margin-left:-50px">Email:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span><input  class="input" type="text" name="Email"   placeholder="Enter mailID" required></span><br>
        <input  style="height:50px; width:120px; background:url(Images/submit_butto.gif) no-repeat right top; border: none;" type="submit"  name="submit" value="">
       <?PHP 
       } 
      else
      {
         $Email=$_POST['Email'];
        if(!empty($Email))
        {
         $model = new UsersModel();
         $rowsCount = $model->checkUserEmail($Email);
          echo $rowsCount;
         if ($rowsCount!=0)
         {
//If you are submitting the form insert the details into database
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("A password hasbeen sent to your Email..");
        window.location.href="LoginViewController.php";</script>';
     }
     else
      {
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("Enter valid email");
        window.location.href="ForgetPasswordViewController.php";</script>';
        }

        }
        }
      ?>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Any suggestions are acceptable....

Comment: What is the specific problem? You don't know how to create the link? You don't know how to send an email?

Comment: @deceze Problem i don't know how to send am email...

Comment: Just an additional interesting read:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069799/1063823

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send mail using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634029/how-to-send-mail-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code if you want to send an email:

```
$to      = 'recepient@somemail.com';
$subject = 'Subject here';
$message = "Content";
$message .= "more Content";
$message .= "even more Content or a variable".$variable;
$headers = 'From: sender@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: sender@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Be aware that there are security issues like header injection if you don't validate the user input. A good email validation is this:

```
$to = $_POST["email"];
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { /*mail is ok*/ }
else {/*mail is NOT ok*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send mail using `PHPMailer`

Here is the simple tutorial for `PHPMailer`

[How to send mail using PHP](http://rohitashv.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/how-to-send-mail-using-php/)

Comment: If you like the answer then you can accept or vote up answers

Comment: But for vote up need some reputation points... i don't have...those. and i already accepted Sergio answer...